# When I cast Time Stop, do I know how many free turns I have?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time

[*Time Stop*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/time-stop) gives the caster a variable number of "free" turns (marked in bold):

> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time passes for other creatures, while you take **1d4 + 1 turns** in a row, during which you can use actions and move as normal.

When I cast *Time Stop*, do I know exactly how many turns I'm getting, thus allowing me to plan exactly the sequence of actions I will take while time is stopped? Or do I only know that the flow of time will resume some time between the end of my 2nd turn and the end of my 5th turn after casting it, requiring me to plan for this uncertainty?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## It doesn't specify when you roll: DM's Choice

The language of the spell doesn't specify when you roll the d4 to determine the number of turns. Technically, it therefore comes down to the DM's decision.

Even though it is a DM's call because of the ambiguity, I can't come up with any reason why you'd limit the caster to not have that knowledge. This is a 9th level spell and having it end abruptly turns this into a *very risky* use that could backfire just as much (if not more) then it will work.

### So let the player roll- it's what my tables do

Let the player roll the d4 when they cast - that's how my tables have used it. The spell limitations themselves are enough to contain what can be done and it lets the caster come up with a fun plan during their time.

Comment: Something I thought of after asking: certain spells (e.g. divinations with a chance of failure) specify that the DM makes a roll in secret. Does the lack of such text imply that the roll does represent player character knowledge?

Comment: @RyanThompson My gut says no. It just feels like WoTC either didn't feel like they needed to state it or just sloppiness. But the lack of "DM rolls" doesn't necessarily mean "player definitely rolls". It's just unclear.

Comment: And just because the player rolls it doesn't mean the characters knows the result. It's a possible metagame-y situation so DM's choice seems good

Comment: @Medix2 To be clear, the ambiguity of the rules makes it DM's Choice. But I choose to give that information to my players (and their player characters.)